# OpenMPI communication over local network[2 machines]

Tags: openmpi

Is there any way to make a MPI program work on two different machines (both windows 7) over local network ? Lets assume that I have 1 PC with local IP 192.168.1.1 and other one with 192.168.1.2. I've heard of DeinoMPI, but isn't there any way to do it faster ?

Answer (score 0):

Prior versions of Open MPI natively supported Microsoft Windows, but that support was dropped due to lack of interest.  The current release series of Open MPI (1.8.x) has Cygwin builds available; check out http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=openmpi (that URL takes a while to load; it seems to be a slow/overloaded server).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Microsoft's MPI offering: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. It's freely available but only supports MPI-1 functions as far as I know.